# Altering the text after a checkbox using the Drupal Form Api

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I got the following issue. A clients wants that the text after checkboxes are links to other pages and thus between ...

I have the following code:

```
$form['boxes_brands'] = array(
        '#type'=>'checkboxes',
        '#title'=>'<div id="title-container">Merken</div>',
        '#options'=>$brandArr,
        '#default_value'=>$_SESSION['filter_brands_cat'],           
    );
```

=> $brandArr is an array of brands.

I looked in the Form Api of Drupal but I did not find an option to do this. I could alter the values in $brandArr but of course that changes the value of the value attribuut of the input object too.

Using the prefix and suffix options won't do it either because I don't want the checkboxes in the  tags too.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created the form with the UI, then you should be able to specify something like this in as the options and links would be rendered as links:

```
google|<a href="http://www.google.com">This is a link to google</a>
yahoo|<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
bing|<a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing!</a>
```

See example: 
[image: Options label as links]

Otherwise, you should be able to modify the `$brandArr` accordingly to create links in the label.  Doing this should NOT change the value of the attribute as it should be a `$value->$label` associative array.  You just need to change the `$label` not the `$value`.